# Web essentials 2013 unused CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

[Following this guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM5oz_2OidI), I am removing unused CSS with Web essentials. 
Great feature overall, but I wonder if there are some settings that I am missing or if the tool aren't just not good enough.

It highlights obviously used styles as unused.

Do I need to teak the tool somehow?

Or is the tool not smart enough to catch selectors like these:

```
.hero h1 {
}
```